# progressdialog is not appearing in OnCreate() while androidmediaplayer is preparing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, oncreate

While Video Activity is working i'm calling the `progressdialog.show()` in `OnCreate()` and when `mediaplayer.start()` method finish its work, i'm creating a thread and starting it to stop the `progressdialog`. Whatever i tried, progressdialog is not appearing even if it works(in debug mod i checked it) in `Oncreate()`. I tried `AsyncTask` `OnPostExecute()` , `OnPreExecute` result is still the same : `ProgressDialog` is appearing just one second and dismiss. Where am i doing wrong, i couldn't find. Hope I could explain myself.

Thanks in advance.

**Tried this :**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle onSaveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(onSaveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoActivity.this, "", "Loading...");
 //Codes 
}
//Long proccess
void playVideo() {
mMediaPlayer.start();
mMediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            progressDialog.dismiss();               
        }
    });
    th.start(); 
 }
```

**And this :**

```
  class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Loading..."); // Yükleniyor                                                                      // mesajı                                                                       // veriyoruz
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
          //DoingBackground()..
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use

`progressDialog.dismiss();`

inside run() it will disappear when thread starts.

Comment: yes i know my problem is not dismiss. it is about starting,showing in oncreate.